# Integrating GWT into existing website

Tags: gwt

I do have an existing website, and now I want to add a map (like google map) into that application. I want to use GWT since I can write simple java for the processing.

Is it possible to integrate GWT into my existing application? Like

Map map = new Map();
...

Site.getDiv("myDiv").add(map)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can use google maps with gwt
https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api